# Change MainWindow Content by ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i am new to wpf and xaml and try to change the content of a window (Login -> Main content and main content -> Login) in an WindowsApplication (Xaml, WPF). So far i have the following for this simple login/logout scenario:

1. BaseViewModel

   ```
   public class BaseViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```
2. BaseMainViewViewModel (Base class for setting the MainViewType Property in the MainWindow. It also contains the command to change the property via the button in the MainViews.)

   ```
   public class BaseMainViewViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {
       private static MainViewType _CurrentMainView;
       private ICommand _SwitchMainViewCommand;

       public BaseMainViewViewModel()
       {
           SwitchMainViewCommand = new RelayCommand(SwitchMainView);
       }

       public MainViewType CurrentMainView
       {
           get { return _CurrentMainView; }
           set
           {
               if (value != _CurrentMainView)
               {
                   _CurrentMainView = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentMainView));
               }
           }
       }

       public ICommand SwitchMainViewCommand
       {
           get { return _SwitchMainViewCommand; }
           set { _SwitchMainViewCommand = value; }
       }

       #region Test

       public void SwitchMainView(object param)
       {
           Debugger.Break();
           switch (CurrentMainView)
           {
               case MainViewType.Login:
                   CurrentMainView = MainViewType.Main;
                   break;
               case MainViewType.Main:
                   CurrentMainView = MainViewType.Login;
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
           MessageBox.Show("Login/Logout");
       }

       #endregion Test
   ```
3. LoginViewModel inherites from BaseMainViewViewModel to get access to the CurrentMainView-Property

   ```
   public class LoginViewModel : BaseMainViewViewModel {}
   ```
4. MainViewModel her the same

   ```
   public class MainViewModel : BaseMainViewViewModel {}
   ```
5. MainWindowViewModel

   ```
   public class MainWindowViewModel: BaseMainViewViewModel {}
   ```
6. LoginMainView

   ```
   public partial class LoginMainView : UserControl
   {
       public LoginMainView()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
       }
   }
   ```

   Currently i have only one button (Login-Button) in the LoginMainView. If I click this button, the current LoginMainView should be exchanged with the MainMainView.

   ```
   <Grid>
     <Button Content="Main" Background="Red" Command="{Binding SwitchMainViewCommand}" />
   </Grid>
   ```
7. MainMainView

   ```
   public partial class MainMainView : UserControl
   {
       public LoginMainView()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = new MainViewModel();
       }
   }
   ```

   here the same (Logout-Button) correspond to LoginMainView...

   ```
   <Grid>
     <Button Content="Logout" Background="Green" Command="{Binding SwitchMainViewCommand}" />
   </Grid>
   ```
8. MainWindow

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
       }
   }
   ```

   In the MainWindow-View i bind the CurrentMainView-Property (MainViewType) from the BaseMainViewViewModel to the contentpresenter, which i will change by clicking the button in the MainMainView/LoginMainView and the ValueConverter shold do the rest.

   ```
   <Grid>
     <StackPanel>
       <Label Content="Test" />
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentMainView, Converter={view:MainViewValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
     </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```
9. MainViewType

   ```
   public enum MainViewType
   {
       Login = 0,
       Main = 1
   }
   ```
10. BaseValueConverter

    ```
    public abstract class BaseValueConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    where T : class, new()
    {
        private static T _Converter = null;

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return _Converter ?? (_Converter = new T());
        }

        public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

        public abstract object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    }
    ```
11. RelayCommand

    ```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {

        private Action<object> _Execute;
        private Predicate<object> _CanExecute;

        private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute) { }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _Execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _CanExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("canExecute");
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return (_CanExecute != null) && _CanExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _Execute(parameter);
        }

        public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            EventHandler eventHandler = CanExecuteChangedInternal;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public void Destroy()
        {
            _CanExecute = _ => false;
            _Execute = _ => { return; };
        }

        private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    ```

When i start the application, the ValueConverter is called and the correct View (LoginMainView) is loaded. I then click on the button in the LoginMainView, the command (SwitchMainView) is executed, but then the content of MainWindow is not changed into MainMainView because the ValueConverter is not used.

What am i doing wrong? Do i have a fundamental understanding problem? Or is it not possible in this way to map the simple login/logout scenario? Or did i simply overlook something? Can someone please tell me what i have forgotten?

Many thanks in advance to the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ValueConverter for that. You are on a right track thoug. Take a look [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing) - this is sample application for ReactiveUI framework (which is my favourite).

It has AppBootrsapper (ViewModel of the application). As the framework does some magick around it, the basic idea is:

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:rx="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI;assembly=ReactiveUI"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" >
           <ContentControl  Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
                  <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LoginViewModel}">
<!-- here you put your content wof login screen, prefereably as seperate UserControl -->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MainViewModel}">
<!-- here you put your content main screen, prefereably as seperate UserControl -->
</DataTemplate>
 </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then you just set `AppBootstrapper.ActiveViewModel = new LoginViewModel()` and you have login screen.

If you login, `AppBootstrapper.ActiveViewModel = new MainViewModel()` and WPF displays main screen.

All that and much more is done by ReactiveUI framwork - only there instead of putting DataTemplates for ViewModels, you register UserControls as views and RoutedViewHost does all the magick. Don't do that on your own, it's inventing the wheel again.

EDIT to answer the comment:

You put `AppBootstrapper.ActiveViewModel = new MainViewModel()` in your NavigationService. Navigation meaning the thing that changes displayed view. Most common version is a stack, which top is active ViewModel. When you press Back button, you just pop the stack.

This all applies to MVVM model with Model First navigation, which means you first instantiate ViewModel, and navigation service finds the proper view.

You can do this in the other way: View First navigation. There are some tutorials for WPF page navigation. It works exactly the same, but instead of ViewModel, you create a page (a view) which then creates underlying data.

MVVM app model is so popular, because it allows very clean logic and presentation separation (XAML is ONLY about view, ViewModels contain all logic, Models persist the data), which in turn makes it very easy to share logic between platforms. In fact, if you do that correctly, you can use all your ViewModels in apps written in Xamarin, WPF or UWP, just by creating platform-specific views.

To wrap up, WPF allows you to switch in a property data and it will find a view for it automatically (via DataTemplates). Remember about INotifyPropertyChanged and everything will work

Comment: Ok, first of all thanks for the answer. But to learn and understand WPF and XAML better, i would like to reinvent the wheel. ;-) So what would i have to do to implement it in the manner described above? What i still missing? Btw. where do i put `AppBootstraper.ActiveViewModel = new LoginViewModel()`? Do i have to create two commands for this an bind them to the respective buttons?